# Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
<% if (users.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="grid">
            <% for(user of users) { %>
                <article class="card product-item">
                    <header class="card__header">
                        <h1 class="product__title">user.Username</h1>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <button class="btn">Go to profile</button>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    <% } else { %>
        <h3>No users are registered yet!</h3>
    <% } %>
```

Inside the if statement > (greater than) sign is recognizing as closing tag. What should I do?

Comment: This works fine for me - altough you should change it to `<h1 class="product__title"><%= user.Username %></h1>` to set the username.  Are you sure this is the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

There are no syntax errors in the code supplied when tested using the following code (question code is contained in the `template` variable):

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

let template = `
<% if (users.length > 0) { %> 
    <div class="grid"> 
        <% for(user of users) { %> 
            <article class="card product-item"> 
                <header class="card__header"> 
                    <h1 class="product__title">user.Username</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="card__actions">
                    <button class="btn">Go to profile</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        <% } %>
    </div>
<% } else { %>
    <h3>No users are registered yet!</h3>
<% } %>
`;

const renderData = {
    users: [{
        Username: 'test'
    }]
};
const output = ejs.render(template, renderData);

console.log(output);
```

Console output:

```
    <div class="grid">

            <article class="card product-item">
                <header class="card__header">
                    <h1 class="product__title">user.Username</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="card__actions">
                    <button class="btn">Go to profile</button>
                </div>
            </article>

    </div>
```

However, as noted by @eol, `user.Username` should be wrapped in output tags.